# How to realtime highlighting

Tags: django, syntax-highlighting

Does anybody know how can I make real-time highlighting in forms in Django?

Here's what I'm doing: I have a model, and a few instances of it. I'm serializing the selected object to json and sending it to my form (e.g. textarea). Then I can edit it, deserialize, and send it back to the db. Are there any options for highligting this json text in real time?

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?

Comment: http://codemirror.net/ I need something like this. But much simpler.